# Can Asterisk 11 act as ICE server?

Tags: asterisk, ice, stun

I have recently installed Asterisk 11.4 on my VM. I wanted to know if Asterisk 11 can act as a ICE server ? In Asterisk 11's wiki page , there is a mention of ICE but those configurations are for Asterisk to act as a end device and not as a server. There is a mention of stunserver and turnserver which the Asterisk device must use to send STUN/TURN requests.... Is it not possible for Asterisk itself to act as STUN/TURN server?

Answer (score 2):

It can not be ICE and STUN and TURN, but it supports both after version 11.

see bellow:

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Interactive+Connectivity+Establishment+(ICE)+in+Asterisk

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/~jcolp/ICE,+STUN,+and+TURN+Support

Answer (score 1):

No, asterisk not support of ice/stun server inside asterisk.
Asterisk is VOIP !!!! server.
Very bad idea put anything in it.

So it not support ice, stun,jabber etc.

Read this about ice servers availibe:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/ICE

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN

https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If Asterisk 11 DOES NOT support ICE , then why do we enable icesupport in Asterisk 11 server ? What is the use of setting STUN and TURN addresses in the Asterisk server when its the end-devices which do the STUN/TURN query and not the server?

Comment: the previous comment @arheops

Comment: Client code needed to got external address for NAT traversal.